# MongoDB how to fetch documents based on multiple dates

Tags: mongodb, date

I have a collection of events, each have a start date. I want to fetch data starting on specific dates only. How will i do that ? I found a lot of solutions for date ranges but this case is different. If client inputs two dates i need to fetch only the events starting on those two dates, no need of dates in between. I tried using $or, $in etc but no use. The below code will not work.

```
let query = {
  startDate: {
    $or: [
      {
        $gte: new Date("2018-05-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date("2018-05-10T23:59:59.000Z")
      },
      {
        $gte: new Date("2018-08-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date("2018-08-06T23:59:59.000Z")
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
let query = {
  $or: [
    {
      startDate: {
        $gte: new Date("2018-05-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date("2018-05-10T23:59:59.000Z")
      }
    },
    {
      startDate: {
        $gte: new Date("2018-08-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date("2018-08-06T23:59:59.000Z")
      }
    }
  ]
};
```